# Qt - QPainter.DrawText doesnt draw the text

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter, drawtext

I'm creating an analog clock in Qt-Creator 5, now I want to draw the numbers to the screen, but it doesn't work?

```
painter.drawText(QPoint(50, 50), "12");
```

I absolutely don't see the point why it doesn't work. when I replace this line in my code with a `.drawEllipse`, it works fine. So the position/color can't be the problem, except `drawText` would not use the `setBrush()` color.

Anyone knows how to correctly draw text on the screen with the `QPainter`?

```
//previous code only draws blue ellipses with white background
QColor secondColor(240,0,0);

painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
painter.setBrush(secondColor);
painter.save();

QFont font=painter.font() ;
font.setPointSize(18);
painter.setFont(font);
painter.drawText(QPoint(50, 50), "12");
```

because it's at the end of `paintEvent` it can't be overdrawn

Comment: Could be your pen color. Could be you're painting something on top. There's really no way of knowing where your bug is without a piece of code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: i've added some code, but its at the end of paintEvent, so overdrawing cant be the problem. color is Red, also no problem because everything other is white

Comment: `painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);`?

Comment: i guess in the analog-clock-tutorial from QT the pen always got setted to `Qt::NoPen` and in no drawText code snippet i saw a `setPen`. checked it now by setting it to red and worked. thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setting the pen-style over

```
 painter.setPen(colorStyle);
```

solved the problem. thanks to Mat